# creating xml file

Tags: php, xml

I am creating xml file as below, can anybody help how to get that using php?

xml file:

```
<products>
<product id="123" />
</products>
```

Php file:

i am using following code but not getting result as above

```
$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$products= $xml->createElement('products');
$product = $xml->createElement('product');
$id = $xml->createElement('id');
$xml->appendChild($products);
$products->appendChild($product);
$product->appendChild($id);
$id->nodeValue = 123; 
$xml->save("data.xml");
```

retrieving xml data:

```
         $xml = new DomDocument();
         $xmlFile = "data.xml";
         $xml= DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
         $product = $xml->getElementsByTagName("product");             
         foreach($product as $node) 
            { 
        $address = $node->getElementsByAttributeName("address");
        $address = $address->item(0)->nodeValue;
          echo"$address";
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the results you want because you're adding `id` as a tag rather than an attribute. I just refactored your code a little and made `id` an attribute. I tested the code below and it produces your desired result.

```
<?php
$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$products= $xml->createElement('products');
$product = $xml->createElement('product');
$xml->appendChild($products);
$products->appendChild($product);
$product->appendChild(new DomAttr('id', '123'));
$xml->save("data.xml");
?>
```

Comment: yes it exactly what i wanted. but if i want to echo 'id' value after xml file created then what changes should i made after loading xml file

Comment: @rick: You could add the line `echo $product->getAttribute('id');` at the end of my example code to echo out the `id`.

Comment: i have given example above 'retrieving xml data' can i use ur this line in my example....sorry i am new to xml

Comment: @rick: It looks the the structure of the xml doc that you're reading is different. The original xml has `<products>` and `<product>` and your reader has `<marker>` and `<address>`. They don't look compatible. In any case, please post a new question rather than changing this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is to be an attribute, then you need to use the `DOMElement::setAttribute()` method. I think this will work - a[ccording to the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php), if an attribute doesn't already exist it will be created.

```
$product->setAttribute("id", "123");
```

Then loas the `$product->appendChild( $id );`